# Unity Launcher Icons gets fuzzy when on odd numbered setting

Tags: unity, graphics, settings

## **Fuzzy icons when odd number-sized in launcher bar - unity**

---

### *Description of the problem*

When entering the appearance settings in the system tools, you can change the unity **icon-size** with a slider. When making this slider go on odd numbers (e.g. 41, 43, 39), go can note a notable difference in the quality of the icons. This is because the launcher is saving resources on the quality when having smaller icons on the unity-bar, but why is unity doing this on all the odd-numbered sizes?

### Question

How can i make the icons remain big-resolouted when making odd-numbered icon-size? I have attached 2 screenshots to describe my problem where i used **40** and **39** as setting on the slider.[image: Image with 39 as setting] and [image: Image where 40 is setting]

You might want to zoom in on the pictures to watch the difference. And i am probably considering this as a bug; in 13.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a bug that can be fixed. The problem is that the icons are being scaled, because they are not drawn in every enumeration of pixel sizes that could be used. When you choose an odd pixel size, the scaling results in a blurrier icon than you would otherwise normally get when scaling to an even pixel size.

If anything, the bug is that the choice of icon size is a scale which selects absolute pixel sizes, rather than having a few sizes listed in the code, and described as 'Small', 'Medium', 'Large', etc… in the UI.

Comment: Thanks, i'll note that. Not a big issue though, but worth mentioning :P